# How to get current domain and directory name dynamically php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress, Right now i am working with "my server", and my current domain/main url is like "myurl.com/myproject"
And later i will move project(wordpress) to another server and url will be like "myurl.com", so i want to know that right now how can
i manage this ? in other words which code should be use for include "css,js,images etc.." ?
I tried with following code not showing "http"

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Comment: $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] Build your paths off of the root.

Comment: [`__DIR__`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can get your domain URL via `home_url('/')` [home_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/) and get your current directory via PHP function and constant `basename(___FILE___)` [**FILE**_](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) [basename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) or use WordPress function to create your desire dircetory path `get_template_directory().'/your_dir'` [get_template_directory](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory/) or URL `get_template_directory_uri().'/your_dir'` [get_template_directory_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/)

Comment: Note - that if you use a child theme, the functions `get_stylesheet_directory()` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` should be used instead, since the template functions always returns the parent themes directory - Otherwise, good answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
function get_url(){
    // Start memory cache
    static $parse_url;
    // Return cache
    if($parse_url) {
        return $parse_url;
    }
    // Check is SSL
    $is_ssl = (
        ( is_admin() && defined('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN') && FORCE_SSL_ADMIN ===true )
        || (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')
        || (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
        || (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == 'on')
        || (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)
        || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT'] == 443)
        || (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] == 'https')
    );
    // Get protocol HTTP or HTTPS
    $http = 'http'.( $is_ssl ? 's' : '');
    // Get domain
    $domain = preg_replace('%:/{3,}%i','://',rtrim($http,'/').'://'.(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : ''));
    $domain = rtrim($domain,'/');
    // Combine all and get full URL
    $url = preg_replace('%:/{3,}%i','://',$domain.'/'.(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && !empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ? ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'): ''));
    //Save to cache
    $parse_url = array(
        'method'    =>  $http,
        'home_fold' =>  str_replace($domain,'',home_url()),
        'url'       =>  $url,
        'domain'    =>  $domain,
    );
    // Return
    return $parse_url;
}
```

I build this function to work in one my plugin that cover all WordPress and PHP versions.

Tested on few thousand installations.

Feel free to use it!